# hardware board to learn OS programming

Tags: embedded-systems

I need a single board computer, on which I can easily learn bare-bone OS programming. In particular I need something like Raspberry PI, but:

- execution power must be circa about Raspberry Pi 3
- must have Wi-Fi and Bluetooth built on board
- must have very very good documentation (best if hardware was open source also)
- architecture should be multicore ARM or multicore Intel (generation does not matter)
- must also have possibility to use board to control external devices ( should have couple of GPIOs, some SPI communication etc.)

Comment: You mention the Raspberry Pi 3 in your question. Does the Raspberry Pi 3 not meet all these requirements, or do you need some analog I/O's?

Comment: Problem is, that raspberry pi3 is not open hardware and also all raspberries have a really poor documentation. But closed hardware is still a bigger issue, as when writing OS, I cannot use closed drivers, because they will not be supported(because they are written only for Linux/Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd post as a comment but I can't do that.  What about the Orange Pi?

http://www.orangepi.org/

ARM 
Open Source 
Docs might be lacking though 
Can control things

Comment: quite a good thing. Missing docs can be a problem though. Do you know how does it look like if it is about stability of the firmware? Eg. in raspberryPi different firmwares may cause low level programs to stop working. Does something like this take place on OrangePi as well?

Comment: I can't answer that, I don't have experience with it. It can run several different operating systems including Android, my guess is you might run into issues depending on what you're trying to accomplish.